# How to update `nodejs` in `ubuntu` platform?

Tags: ubuntu, node.js

When I console in my `ubuntu` platform I am getting the following to check the `node` details.

here is the ouput:

```
dev@ubuntu14044:~$ nodejs -v
v0.10.25
dev@ubuntu14044:~$ node -v
v7.8.0
dev@ubuntu14044:~$ npm -v
4.4.4
dev@ubuntu14044:~$
```

to upgrade my `nodejs` - I tried like this: `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` But allways I am getting the `nodejs` version as `v0.10.25` But I want to update that in to latest as `7.x` how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packaged nodejs installs version 0.10.25

You'll have to remove it first

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs*
```

Then as mentioned on [node.js website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions), setup a ppa & then install

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: If I run all commands you given, I am getting this error : `## Confirming "n/a" is supported...

+ curl -sLf -o /dev/null 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x/dists/n/a/Release'

## Your distribution, identified as "n/a", is not currently supported, please contact NodeSource at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues if you think this is incorrect or would like your distribution to be considered for support
` - how to fix this?

Comment: what distro are you using

Comment: I am not getting you.. `distro` stands for?